# algorithm for feature extraction from audio signals

Tags: matlab, audio, algorithms

I am trying to build a model for speaker identification, and I understand that the first step is to extract the features from the audio signals that are in my database. I have done quite a bit of research and cant find how to do this extraction and to which features. How do I select which features to extract to? what would be the algorithm? Can someone please point me to either an algorithm that I could implement or a sample matlab code?

Answer (score 3):

For speaker recognition, the features you should probably start with are [MFCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum).

There are libraries offering MFCC extraction modules, such as [YAAFE](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/), [aubio](http://aubio.org/) (C/C++), the MIR toolbox or Dan Ellis' [implementation](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/rosa/matlab/rastamat/) (Matlab) - and of course speech recognition frameworks (Sphinx, HTK) provides MFCC extraction tools.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link.

https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19236-some-basic-audio-features

It computes various features

1. Energy Entropy Standard Deviation (std)
2. Signal Energy Std by Mean (average) Ratio
3. Zero Crossing Rate Std
4. Spectral Rolloff Std
5. Spectral Centroid Std
6. Spectral Flux Std by Mean Ratio